# Modify msbuild command line arguments inside msbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Essentially, what I want to do, is to be able to write my program commandline within the msbuild file itself. This could have many advantages, like being able to use different commandline depending on $Conditions and being able to have them saved directly in the .csproj for posterity and version control.

Is it possible? Pseudo code:

```
<Commandline>
/test=test /Name=test /Mode=whatever /lotsMore=more,more
</Commandline>
```

Then the .csproj this is in, should be using this commandline when executed.

Answer (score 0):

MsBuild is way ahead of you.  Most of those command-line parameters translate to properties within an msbuild project file, so you could as an alternative make conditional property groups.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Name>Default Name</Name>
    <Mode>Default</Mode>
    <Test></Test>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="$(Test)=='true'">
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <Mode>Whatever</Mode>
    <Test>test</Test>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Did you try this? I do a /test=world and in the AfterBuild step I do a Message task with Text="Hello $(test)" but it only prints "Hello". Apart from that, it wouldn't allow me to add any "property" to the commandline that it doesn't already have right?